# Будут ли переписываться данные в файле, если название файла одно и то же?

Tags: python, файлы

Будут ли **переписываться данные** в файле, если название файла одно и то же? Пример кода:

```py
with open("C:/Users/SERGEY/PycharmProjects/ТЕСТ/venv/Товары.csv", "a",
          encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    ...
```

Или данные будут дописываться внизу строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем коде, данные будут дописываться внизу.

Добавляю всю таблицу режимов открытия файла (mode, второй параметр функции open):

| Символ | Пояснение |
| --- | --- |
| 'r' | Открыть для чтения (по умолчанию) |
| 'w' | Открыть для записи, удаляет содержимое, если файл существует |
| 'x' | Открыть и создать файл, ошибка, если файл уже существует |
| 'a' | открыть для записи, добавив в конец файла, если он существует |
| 'b' | бинарный режим |
| 't' | текстовый режим (по умолчанию) |
| '+' | открыть для обновления (чтение и запись) |

Comment: Огромное спасибо))

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, всё написано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> 'a' - open for writing, appending to the end of file if it exists

У вас выбран режим добавления в конец файла "a". Режим открытия файла `mode=` - это второй параметр функции `open`:

> open(file, **mode**='r', buffering=- 1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)

```py
with open("C:/Users/SERGEY/PycharmProjects/ТЕСТ/venv/Товары.csv", "a",
                                                                  ^^^ режим доступа к файлу
```